# Как изменить размер очереди (Queue)?

Tags: python

Как изменить размер очереди (`Queue.Queue`) после создания?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я должен ее нагуглить для вас или это намек что там есть ответ?

Comment: `"после создания"`.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Либо вы устанавливаете сразу необходимый размер, либо не задаете вовсе, тогда будет считаться что очередь "бесконечна".